# AngularJS version issue?

Tags: angularjs

I am a learner, and sorry if it is not the right place to ask a trivial question, please direct me to the suitable forum.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Angular Example: 2</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="FirstCtrl.js"> </script>

</head>

<body>


<!-- Controllers-->

<div ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <h1>{{data.message + " world"}}</h1>
        <div class="{{data.message}}">
            Wrap me in a foundation component
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

FirstCtrl.js

```
function FirstCtrl($scope){

    $scope.data = {message: "Hello"};
}
```

If I use the following version it works.

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

How can I decide which one to use? What is the issue here

Comment: Global controllers were disabled in 1.3.0-beta.15. Read the breaking change here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-15

Comment: Use ng-class="data.message" instead of class="{{data.message}}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments **`tasseKATT`** specified exactly what is going on correctly.

In order to resolve this using angular 1.3+ you must define your module, both in markup and in code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Then add your controller to that module:

```
              //name of the controller \/
angular.module('myApp').controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl);
           //function that defines your controller /\
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please suggest me best resource or book to learn (probably the latest version) of AngularJS? I face lot of difficulty even to execute the ready-made code given with tutorials available online. Thanks and appreciate your help.

Comment: Honestly there aren't many external breaking changes from 1.2.x to 1.3.x except for this one that you have already crossed. There a lot of performance improvements and some extras added, so I would stick to what you've found so far re: 1.2.x for reference.